# TextField loses focus when State changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am dynamically creating a form according to the button clicks, so when the user presses the button, the form generates with a new id. SO, i created a state for the createform counter like this,

```
const [formmakersno, setFormmakersno] = useState([0]);
```

and inside my render, I have something like this :

```
{formmakersno.map((no) => {
      return formDetails;
    })}
```

My "formDetails" is a constant with jsx, it just returns the form elements like a textfield and a button. Everything works fine, Everytime i click the button the form generates as expected, But, I want to pass the counter number every-time it creates a new form, as a prop, since i cannot do this when it is just a const which returns a jsx, I converted it into an arrow function so that i can pass props and passed it like this :

```
{formmakersno.map((no) => {
      return <formDetails value={no} />;
    })}
```

And i could access the props too, but the problem is that , everytime I type inside the textfield for each letter the textfield goes out of focus, because its a component it renders everytime because I am calling an Onchange method with a state change inside it. Is there a workaround for this ?

EDIT : I created this simple example to further illustrate the problem I am facing :

```
    export const CreatePush2 = () => {
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState(["", ""]);
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([0, 1, 2]);

  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    let titles_1 = [...titles];
    let titles_11 = titles_1[id];
    titles_11 = value;
    setTitles(titles_1);
    console.log(titles);
  };

  const InputCreator = ({ id }) => {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, id)} value={titles[id]} />
        <br />
      </form>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {numbers.map((number) => {
        return <InputCreator key={number.toString()} id={number} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreatePush2;
```

The textfield loses focus with every letter typed.

Comment: An example would help, but my first guess would be that it could be due to missing a key when you map your render (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). May also help if the text field you render was memoized via React.memo, though this usually means there might be something off with how you are handling/passing state if that works.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using keys, but still I am facing the same problem. I have updated my question with an example as you suggested.

Comment: You may want to look into restructuring how you are passing state and rendering components. Here is a sandbox that 'fixes' some render issues. https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-mayer-nl2dv?file=/src/App.js Basically what was happening before is that you were creating a new instance of input every time your state change. This will cause your focus to break as its a whole new component instead of being reused.

Comment: Thank you ! So the answer was to use callbacks, is there a better way I could perform this ? Because I will be doing this for a form with much more components and many such forms.

Comment: Honestly? I'd recommend looking into https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik. It's well supported and documented. I personally have been through the hassle of creating my own form system. If you want to continue the exercise tho. There are many ways to accomplish what you want. One way that I've done is by having a central, mutable form state stored in context. I would then implement reusable input components that would use hooks to access the form data inside the context. This way state isn't passed down through through your component tree, preventing rerenders that may break your input focus.